Couldn't add sqs trigger to lambda because of scp restriction
Couldn't add sqs trigger to lambda because of scp restriction, at least that's what AWS support had said.
The issue is that when I try to create the trigger, the following error is raised:

An error occurred when creating the trigger: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS

But when I add trigger getting below error, client is saying it should work if we have sqs vpc endpoint and we have created vpc endpoint and tried using console, awscli, cfn and pipeline still getting same error and I've checked execution role has all required policies and sqs access policy has been verified as well, it's been weeks and client not ready to make changes to scp so we are stuck with this issue.
Is it even possible to add sqs trigger without making changes in scp?

The SCP is doing what it is intended to do, so without making changes to the SCP or using some other role that already has an exclusion in the SCP you won't be able to do this.
